# Trigger radio button change

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

On a form I have a radio group that displays an input field. The field is requried depening on whether or not it's displayed. The user can pull the form back up and the fields are repopulated with the appropriate data. My problem is the form initially loads with the radio group set at `no` (hiding the input field') and I want to trigger the event that is being handled by the listener.

This is the event handler (`#custodian is a < tr>`):

```
$('.passCustodian').change(function(){
    $('#custodian').toggle();
});
```

This is part of the function that repopulates the form fields:

```
if(typeof data["custodianData"][0] != 'undefined'){
    $("#requestForm").fillInputs(data["custodianData"][0]);
    //$('.custodianYes').attr('checked',true);  //this didn't work either
    $('.passCustodian').trigger('change');
}
```

You can see I tried to use the jQuery trigger event, but it is not working. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you don't need to trigger a event.

Use this

```
if(typeof data["custodianData"][0] != 'undefined'){
    $("#requestForm").fillInputs(data["custodianData"][0]);
    $('#custodian').toggle();
}
```

or

```
if($('#custodianData').is(':checked')){
        $("#requestForm").fillInputs(data["custodianData"][0]);
        $('#custodian').toggle();
    }
```